# What is "type of expression" in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, expression

I know what "category of expression" is, but I'm confused with "type of expression".

According to [www.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions):

> Expression evaluation may produce a result.

So, is the type of the result the "type of expression"?

But, also according to [www.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions):, it says:

> Each C++ expression is characterized by two independent properties: A type and a value category.

So, is "type" refering to the type of the expression, or the type of the result of the expression?

I think this may require some knowledge of compilation principles (I don't know anything about it), in the end is the type of the expression first, and then determine the type of the expression result based on it? Or is the type of the result of the expression the type of the expression?

Please give an easy-to-understand explanation from the perspective of compilation principles.

Comment: The type of an expression is the type of the result.  For instance if `x` is an `int`, then the expressions `x` and `x+1` both also have the type `int`.  The value category refers to something else.  For instance, `x` is an lvalue because you can assign to it (it's more complex than that, but that's the basic idea).  `x+1`, however, is an rvalue (more technically a prvalue) because it's a temporary object  that cannot be assigned to.

Comment: I'm not sure what "from the perspective of compilation principles" means.

Comment: Because I heard that in C language, the type of the expression needs to be determined first, and then the type of the result of the expression can be determined, I don't understand how this is going on. @Nathan Pierson

Comment: Can you share links to the statements?

Comment: I try to find some hints in [C++ draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type), but it seems that the exact definition is not that clear; Personally(and deducing from the draft), I think the type of expression can be considered as the type of result that removes any reference, and the value category will determine the exact reference type, and they all compose of the type of result.

Comment: It's not clear to me what distinction you're making between "type of the expression" and "type of the result of the expression" because I understand them to be two alternative descriptions of the same thing - the type of the result that would be produced by evaluating the expression.   Some expressions (e.g. when an operand of `sizeof`) are not evaluated, but the type needs to be known for the compiler to compute the size.

Comment: @Peter I heard that one before and its mostly a (misguided) intuitive distinction between something hard to identify or generalize. In certain cases `x` and `(x)` isn't same. A type of array and expression consisting of an array name isn't same thing.

Comment: "Because I heard that in C language, the type of the expression needs to be determined first, and then the type of the result of the expression can be determined": you heard where? It isn't correct. Doesn't even make sense. And what does C have to do with a C++ question? SO isn't a validation mechanism for random Internet garbage.

Comment: @user207421 `SO isn't a validation mechanism for random Internet garbage` I cannot agree more. But generally it's the garbage what sticks to the walls of people's brainboxes and we end up debunking it quite often.

Comment: @user1806566 _The type of an expression is the type of the result._ Not always

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Interesting. Example please?

Comment: @user207421 `int i = 0; reinterpret_cast<unsigned&>(i);`

Comment: @LanguageLawyer How so? The type and return type are both `unsigned&` there.

Comment: @user207421 the type of the expression is `unsigned`, the type of the [result](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#def:result,glvalue) is `int`.

Comment: @Peter _It's not clear to me what distinction you're making between "type of the expression" and "type of the result of the expression"_ You do not know where to find the definition(s) of «result»? Here they are http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#def:result,glvalue http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#def:result,prvalue

Comment: "Type of the result" looks like obscure concept, and not very useful in practice.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer   I'm not making such a distinction.   The OP is, and I'm querying that.

Answer (score 5):

> > Each C++ expression is characterized by two independent properties: A type and a value category.
>
> So, is "type" refering to the type of the expression

Yes. "type" does refer to the type of the expression there.

> So, is the type of the result the "type of expression"?

Not necessarily. The expression, and the result of the expression are separate things. In some cases the expression and its result do have the same type, while in the other cases those types are different. Furthermore, some expressions don't have any result.

---

Result of an expression is defined in the standard as such:

> [basic.lval]
>
> The result of a glvalue is the entity denoted by the expression.
> The result of a prvalue is the value that the expression stores into its context; a prvalue that has type cv void has no result.
> A prvalue whose result is the value V is sometimes said to have or name the value V.
> The result object of a prvalue is the object initialized by the prvalue; a non-discarded prvalue that is used to compute the value of an operand of a built-in operator or a prvalue that has type cv void has no result object.

---

The type of an expression is defined for each kind of expression. For example:

> [expr.unary.op]
>
> The unary * operator performs indirection.
> Its operand shall be a prvalue of type “pointer to T”, where T is an object or function type.
> The operator **yields an lvalue of type T** denoting the object or function to which the operand points.

The highlighted part means that the category of the expression is lvalue, and the type of the expression is `T`.

For example:

```
int  i = 0;
int* p = &i;
int  j = *p;
```

The type of the expression `*p` is `int` as per the quoted rule. It is an lvalue, and the result is the object - that is also named by the variable `i` - whose type is also `int`.

Furthermore, the section `[expr.type]` specifies rules that may adjust the type of any kind of expression.

Comment: _or the type of the result of the expression? Indirectly yes, in the cases where the expression does produce a result._ Not always

Comment: So what do you call the type of the result? The dynamic type?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You call it the type of the result (of the expression). The dynamic type is something more specific: https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.dynamic.type

Comment: Then can you show a case where the type of result is different from the type of the expression (and from its dynamic type)?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Pinging you too, in case you know the answer. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76872148/what-is-type-of-expression-in-c#comment135521777_76872148

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thanks, should've read the comments. Do you know what's the dynamic type here? Probably `int`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes

Comment: From how I read the standard, (in this answer), there is no  definition of "type of result" as one. There is definition of  "type of expression" and of "result of value cathegory". Matching those two with respective characteristics of expression, we get a (possibly empty) *set* of possible results. The "true" value cathegory and type play role where deduction of fully qualified type, or a binding an expression to formal parameter, or initialization happens, because anything else we can do is  make that expression a part of another one (assignment also an expression and may have a result).

Answer (score -1):

A whole section of standard explains what type is. Because there are multiple cathegories of types. E.g. a function (not a pointer to a function) is a type too. It's not a "data type" in sense of Niklaus Wirth's definition.

Type of expression defines what properties expression may have and is it convertible to something else when used in certain context and, if combined with value cathegory, if such use is legal.

E.g. `void` is a type. An expression having such type cannot be used as a value, for anything. But when you call a function which returns `void`, the call itself an expression of type `void`.

Contrary to that a `void*` is a type of pointer which can be used as a value but cannot be dereferenced or be involved in arithmetics. Because both would requre illegal uses an expression of type `void`, as a gvalue or as argument of `sizeof`.

In English a "type of expression" and a "type of expression's result" are synonymical. "Result of expression" is often a misnomer of contextual semantics involving certain expressions being cast to something else. Sometimes it's even a *result* of limited translation of English text to other languages and back, e.g. when "result" or "cast" do not translate directly (my native language got this issue, we come around by robbing English of its words).

Comment: Your final sentence seems quite meaningless.

Comment: @user207421 only if your language is English or similar language. I know where `Yue Zhou` (mind the name?) comes from.  The line about "determining result of expression"  also familiar to me. It's not "internet garbage" it's a very bad translation of "cast" to our languages without borrowing terms from English. It's a bad translation , because it semantically uses term "type" in a second way, which breaches rules of technical translation.

Comment: It is *your* sentence I find meaningless. 'Misnomer of contextual semantics' means nothing, and 'result of expression' is not even ambiguous, let alone anything else you are ascribing to it here.

Comment: @user207421 Misnomer is "wrong name for". A bad translation of `cast` to my language (and to many other) is "result of". Becuase a bad translator would look in dictionary and finds that "to cast" means "to cause something" most of the time. "Result" is also ambigous in translation because in my language the word verbatim used in different way (it's a "translator's enemy"). A good translator would look in reference material or he had already known, that in English , in context of C+ programming, the word "cast" is synonym  of "type conversion".

Comment: @user207421 There are many ambiguities there. E.g.argument and parameter don't have a difference in translation. There are no separate words for "undefined", "undetermined", "unspecified" and "undeclared" in my language. These all are same single word. We have just to "translit" English ones.

Comment: @user207421 The other example of translator enemy  from English to my language:  word "machine". In mine it still got original Greek meaning for one (something huge) or it can mean "car".

Comment: @user207421 When you say that "there is nothing ambigous about 'result of expression", you are talking from the point of person who either native or _speaks_ English language.You are knowing context and use of both words. Now what I would say here sounds like a heresy, but "technical translators" in many Eastern countries do NOT know foreign language. They can't speak or form phrases. They were instructed how to convert text in one language to text in another. This includes most of specialists who use Englsh for their purposes, but then they quickly discover this dark truth.

Comment: _In English a "type of expression" and a "type of expression's result" are synonymical_ In C++, they are not.

Comment: @Swift I don't know why you're trying to teach me basic English, but the sentence in question is still meaningless. In English. This site is conducted in English, and it is up to you to make yourself understood here.